# Can I use flexbox css to have 4 tables one above other, resizable, up to max window height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Been trying lots of different configurations, never getting a complete solution.
Goal 4 tables, one above the other, each starting at just under 1/4 of the browser height, each vertically resizable, bigger and smaller. 3 other tables resize up/down as the adjusted table is manipulated.

With the code below, the 4 tables will expand (but extend beyond the end of the browser view), and they won't shrink. I know the "resize: vertical" is not part of flexbox, but without I can't adjust at all.

I've used flexbox with rows and been able to expand/shrink horizontally, so assume (ha!) that row->column would work similarly.

Can I achieve my goal with flexbox ?

html:

```
<ul class="4tables">
 <li class="flexible CFS"><table id="table_CFS"></table></li>
 <li class="flexible MFS"><table id="table_MFS"></table></li>
 <li class="flexible SES"><table id="table_SES"></table></li>
 <li class="flexible SAAS"><table id="table_SAAS"></table></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul.4tables {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  max-height: 99vh;
}

li.flexible {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-basis: auto;
  height:21vh;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works if I try it fullsize. The problem is, that `vw` and `vh` are always relative to your viewport (browser-window) size, so you cannot use your code if its not fullsize.
So I'd use `position: absolute` for the `tables`-element. (Remember to use `position: relative` for your wrapper.

```css
.tables-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #f0f
}
.tables {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flexible {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 25%;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables-wrapper">
  <div class="tables">
    <div class="flexible"></div>
    <div class="flexible"></div>
    <div class="flexible"></div>
    <div class="flexible"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If your want it fullscreen, just delete the `tables-wrapper`.

```css
.tables {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.flexible {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 25%;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="tables">
  <div class="flexible"></div>
  <div class="flexible"></div>
  <div class="flexible"></div>
  <div class="flexible"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's helped.  One thing it made me realise was that my class named "4tables" had to be renamed, the 4 prefix was causing issues I hadn't noticed before.   It's not as slick as I'd hoped but better than my earlier attempts.   This is it now ... https://live2.cfsres.com/split